# Selectively linking symbols in archive

Tags: gcc, linker

I have a project that is linking in libcrypto.a. But All I'm interested in is, as an example, the SHA functionality. Is there a way to specify that all other unused functions should be stripped from the resulting binary?

GCC 4.8 is part of the toolchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the GNU linker should pull in only the necessary object files, unless you specify the [`--whole_archive` flag](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html).

If you want dead-code elimination, follow use the following linker flags:

> `-Wl,-static`
>
> Link against static libraries.  Required for dead-code elimination.
>
> `-fvtable-gc`
>
> C++ virtual method table instrumented with garbage collection information for the linker.
>
> `-fdata-sections`
>
> Keeps data in separate data sections, so they can be discarded if unused.
>
> `-ffunction-sections`
>
> Keeps functions in separate data sections, so they can be discarded if unused.
>
> `-Wl,--gc-sections`
>
> Tell the linker to garbage collect and discard unused sections.
>
> `-s`
>
> Strip the debug information, so as to make the code as small as possible.  (I presume that you'd want to do this in a dead-code
> removal build.)

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2003-08/msg00128.html